# How to bind datetime with format dd/mm/yyy in MVC when publish Application to IIS ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, iis, publish

really my problem is simple but i don't know how to solve it.
 i have an `ActionResult` method that return `View` and take `datetime` attribute so i send `datetime` attribute in `ActionLink` like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("ForignSell", "ForignSell", "Reports", new  {Start =@ImpDate.DateConfig},null)
```

the `ImpDate.DateConfig` is the date that i sent to `Action` when i run in local mode the `datetime` binded with this format `dd/MM/YYY` there is no problem till now the problem comes when i publish it in **IIS** the `datetime` binded with this format `MM/DD/YYY` and this make problem to me can any one know why it binded in a different way ?

Comment: Convert date to string `new  {Start =@ImpDate.DateConfig.ToString("dd/MM/yyy")}`

Comment: can you tell me how to make this ?

Comment: Have updated my above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the date object to string format you want:

```
@Html.ActionLink("ForignSell", "ForignSell", "Reports", new  {Start = @ImpDate.DateConfig.ToString("dd/MM/yyy")}, null)
```

The ActionLink helper will be automatically url encode the route data.